# Consolidating goofy jquery code

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello everyone in stackoverflow land,

A while back I did a website for a friend of mine and I did this weird jquery code for the front page of his site.  The short story is he first started out wanting a fade in and fade out with panels with the top navigation separate to having both top navigation highlighted and the panels to fade in and fade out. I had little time to change the HTML and graphics so I no choice, but to do it in jquery with each individual button.  So my question is......  Is there a way I can consolidate this code so If I have 7 or more buttons?

Thanks for the help. The code is on the bottom.

```
$(".block1").css({ opacity: 0.5 });
$(".home").css({ backgroundPosition: '0px 0px' });
$(".home").hover(function(){
    $(".home").css({backgroundPosition: '0px -33px'});
    $(".block1").stop().animate({backgroundPosition: '0px -250px', opacity: 1}, "slow");
    },
    function() {
    $(".home").css({backgroundPosition: '0px 0px'});
    $(".block1").stop().animate({backgroundPosition: '0px -250px', opacity: 0.5}, "slow");
});

$(".block1").css({ opacity: 0.5 });
$(".home").css({ backgroundPosition: '0px 0px' });
$(".block1").hover(function(){
    $(".home").css({backgroundPosition: '0px -33px'});
    $(".block1").stop().animate({backgroundPosition: '0px -250px', opacity: 1}, "slow");
    },
    function() {
    $(".home").css({backgroundPosition: '0px 0px'});
    $(".block1").stop().animate({backgroundPosition: '0px -250px', opacity: 0.5}, "slow");
});

$(".home").click(function(){
    $(window).unload( function () {
        $(".block1").css({backgroundPosition: '0px -250px', opacity: 0.5});
        $(".home").css({backgroundPosition: '0px 0px'});
    });
});
$(".block1").click(function(){
    $(window).unload( function () {
        $(".home").css({backgroundPosition: '0px 0px'});
        $(".block1").css({backgroundPosition: '0px -250px', opacity: 0.5});
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Welcome to Artisserie Bakery</title>
<link href="styles/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="js/jquery-1.4.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.backgroundPosition.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/hover-navs.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/preloadCssImages.jQuery_v5.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".art_content-wrapper").fadeIn("slow");
    $(".art_content ul li a").preloadCssImages();
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="art_wrap">
  <div class="art_header">
        <a href="index.html"><h1 id="art_logo">Artisserie Bakery</h1></a>
  </div>
    <div class="art_nav-wrapper">
        <div class="art_nav">
            <ul>
              <li><a class="home" href="home.html">Home</a></li>
              <li><a class="chefs" href="#">Chefs</a></li>
              <li><a class="products" href="products.html">Products</a></li>
              <li><a class="shopping" href="#">Shopping</a></li>
              <li><a class="events" href="#">Events</a></li>
              <li><a class="contact" href="#">Contact</a></li>
              <li><a class="friends" href="#">Friends</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="art_content-wrapper home-page">
        <div class="art_content">
            <ul>
              <li><a class="block1" href="home.html">Home</a></li>
              <li><a class="block2" href="#">Chefs</a></li>
              <li><a class="block3" href="products.html">Products</a></li>
              <li><a class="block4" href="#">Shopping</a></li>
              <li><a class="block5" href="#">Events</a></li>
              <li><a class="block6" href="#">Contact</a></li>
              <li><a class="block7" href="#">Friends</a></li>
            </ul>
            <br />
        <img src="graphx/sprite-footer.png" alt="" border="0" /></div>

    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
a.home{
    width:88px;
    height:33px;
    text-align:center;
    background:url(../graphx/sprite-navs.png) 0px 0px no-repeat;}
a:hover.home{
    background:url(../graphx/sprite-navs.png) 0px -33px no-repeat;}
a.chefs{
    width:87px;
    height:33px;
    text-align:center;
    background:url(../graphx/sprite-navs.png) -88px 0px no-repeat;}
a:hover.chefs{
    background:url(../graphx/sprite-navs.png) -88px -33px no-repeat;}
a.products{
    width:90px;
    height:33px;
    text-align:center;
    background:url(../graphx/sprite-navs.png) -175px 0px no-repeat;}
a:hover.products{
    background:url(../graphx/sprite-navs.png) -175px -33px no-repeat;}
a.shopping{
    width:89px;
    height:33px;
    text-align:center;
    background:url(../graphx/sprite-navs.png) -265px 0px no-repeat;}
a:hover.shopping{
    background:url(../graphx/sprite-navs.png) -265px -33px no-repeat;}
a.events{
    width:88px;
    height:33px;
    text-align:center;
    background:url(../graphx/sprite-navs.png) -354px 0px no-repeat;}
a:hover.events{
    background:url(../graphx/sprite-navs.png) -354px -33px no-repeat;}
a.contact{
    width:82px;
    height:33px;
    text-align:center;
    background:url(../graphx/sprite-navs.png) -442px 0px no-repeat;}
a:hover.contact{
    background:url(../graphx/sprite-navs.png) -442px -33px no-repeat;}
a.friends{
    width:88px;
    height:33px;
    text-align:center;
    background:url(../graphx/sprite-navs.png) -524px 0px no-repeat;}
a:hover.friends{
    background:url(../graphx/sprite-navs.png) -524px -33px no-repeat;}

a.block1{
    display:block;
    text-indent:-9999px;
    background:url(../graphx/sprite-pages.png) 0px -250px no-repeat;
    height:250px;
    width:88px;
    opacity: 0.5;}
a:hover.block1{
    background:url(../graphx/sprite-pages.png) 0px -250px no-repeat;}
a.block2{
    display:block;
    text-indent:-9999px;
    background:url(../graphx/sprite-pages.png) -88px -250px no-repeat;
    height:250px;
    width:87px;
    opacity: 0.5;}
a:hover.block2{
    background:url(../graphx/sprite-pages.png) -88px -250px no-repeat;}
a.block3{
    display:block;
    text-indent:-9999px;
    background:url(../graphx/sprite-pages.png) -175px -250px no-repeat;
    height:250px;
    width:90px;
    opacity: 0.5;}
a:hover.block3{
    background:url(../graphx/sprite-pages.png) -175px -250px no-repeat;}
a.block4{
    display:block;
    text-indent:-9999px;
    background:url(../graphx/sprite-pages.png) -265px -250px no-repeat;
    height:250px;
    width:89px;
    opacity: 0.5;}
a:hover.block4{
    background:url(../graphx/sprite-pages.png) -265px -250px no-repeat;}
a.block5{
    display:block;
    text-indent:-9999px;
    background:url(../graphx/sprite-pages.png) -354px -250px no-repeat;
    height:250px;
    width:88px;
    opacity: 0.5;}
a:hover.block5{
    background:url(../graphx/sprite-pages.png) -354px -250px no-repeat;}
a.block6{
    display:block;
    text-indent:-9999px;
    background:url(../graphx/sprite-pages.png) -442px -250px no-repeat;
    height:250px;
    width:82px;
    opacity: 0.5;}
a:hover.block6{
    background:url(../graphx/sprite-pages.png) -442px -250px no-repeat;}
a.block7{
    display:block;
    text-indent:-9999px;
    background:url(../graphx/sprite-pages.png) -524px -250px no-repeat;
    height:250px;
    width:88px;
    opacity: 0.5;}
a:hover.block7{
    background:url(../graphx/sprite-pages.png) -524px -250px no-repeat;}
```

Comment: Is it just the block number that changes for each button or are there other parameters that differ for each one?

Comment: There different from one another.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are using classes, there are some redundancies.  I think this consolidates it:

```
var block1Classes = $(".block1");
var homeClasses = $(".home");
var block1HomeClasses = $(".home, .block1");

block1Classes.css({ opacity: 0.5 });
homeClasses.css({ backgroundPosition: '0px 0px' });
block1HomeClasses.hover(function(){
    homeClasses.css({backgroundPosition: '0px -33px'});
    block1Classes.stop().animate({backgroundPosition: '0px -250px', opacity: 1}, "slow");
    },
    function() {
    homeClasses.css({backgroundPosition: '0px 0px'});
    block1Classes.stop().animate({backgroundPosition: '0px -250px', opacity: 0.5}, "slow");
});

block1HomeClasses.click(function(){
    $(window).unload( function () {
        block1Classes.css({backgroundPosition: '0px -250px', opacity: 0.5});
        homeClasses.css({backgroundPosition: '0px 0px'});
    });
});
```

Comment: Also, in the name of goodness and harmony, cache some of those jQuery lookups!!

Comment: Would I have to use an array for say if I have 7 or more buttons?

Comment: @rosscj2533 Also, shorter variable names would improve readability.

Comment: @blackbull77 - If your buttons use the same class as the existing button(s), this will work fine.  If your existing button uses the `home` class, and you are adding new buttons with a `button` class, you'd just have to change the initial selector to select the button classes as well - `var homeClasses = $('.home, .button');`. (In that case you'd probably want to change that variable name).

Comment: @Šime Vidas - I agree, but I went for clarity in my answer.  The OP can cut those names down if wanted.

Comment: I think that's better - if it were me, I might be inclined to give meaningful names to all those positioning constants (like "0px 0px") too, or perhaps the object constants (the arguments passed to `.animate()` )

Comment: A brain fart just came to me....  The images where 2 separate sprite sheets. So, what to do if you have to change the backgroundPostion? It just popped into my head when I was reading Pointy's comment.

Comment: @blackbull77 - so you are saying that the different buttons will have different backgroundPositions? That would complicate things. It would probably help to see your html and know what positions each button should have.

Comment: @rosscj2533 - I updated to show HTML and CSS.  At the moment he's happy with what he's got,  I was just wondering if there was a way to change backgroundPosition.  I just wanted to take another step farther with it and see what I can come up with.